# What could be the distribution of an explosion energy of a mining-grade and seismic exploration explosives?

Tags: experimental-physics, waves, statistics, data-analysis

Seismic exploration involves the excitation of seismic waves using the industrially made explosive charges.

What could be the distribution of explosion energy of such a charges?

My guess is that it could be gaussian with mean that can be derived from the charge specs and with very small dispersion. However, the acquisition of the explosion wavefield on the earth surface suggests that the distribution has very strong skewness (right tail is very long).

Here is the distribution of the five million measurements of six thousand explosions registered by eight thousand receivers on one hundred square kilometers area (1%-99% clip):

[image]

And here is the distribution of per-shot average absolute amplidute:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a graph/illustration to clarify what you mean?

Comment: Yeah I don't know either, but are you talking about using explosive charges underground to excite seismic waves? Explosive devices are generally fairly uniform, so the error contribution due to the explosives themselves would probably be negligible; more important might be the variance involved in how well the explosion mechanically couples to the type of rock in its immediate vicinity, since there ought to be a lot of variance in the type and mechanical properties of the rock where you place each different charge.

Comment: Since it is not clear what is being graphed in the upper figure I am totally in the dark about why you would expect it to be central in the first place; indeed my guess at what it represents is something I would *expect* to favor small signals. I'm going to re-ope for the time being, but only to get this some more exposure, not because I can award it a stamp of approval.

Comment: @dmckee: In seismic exploration, a seismic wave is excitated at a points on a certain grid on a surface of the exploration area of interest. The generated wavefield is then registered over small period of time by the grid of seismic receivers forming a pattern around the point of excitation. The first picture shows the distribution of mean absolute amplitudes of all registered events obtained during the series of excitations. The X axes for both pictures are amplitudes. The Y axes are relative number of occurences.

Comment: Mean absolute amplitude of *what*? If it is the mean energy of the wave where it is measured then you should *expect* mostly low values because there are more sensors that are far from the original site than close. But we can't advise you until you are really clear about what these things mean. Or unless someone else in the same field looks at them (assume these are highly standard in your business).

Comment: Seismic receivers are mostly inductive sensors that convert the vibrations of the ground (thus the vibrations of the internal coil against a magnet) into electric current. The current is digitized to provide the amplitudes. The absolute amplitudes of each sensor oscillations are meaned over the period of explotion event registration time, yielding the [i]mean absolute amplitude[/i]. The distribution of that is plotted on the first chart. As you suggest, we have much more weak amplitudes (peak at X=0.2) than strong ones (large tail).